# Laravel PHP query "where not certain id"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have a query where I look for a certain user with a first and a lastname. However I want to make sure that the user that is using it doesn't see his own name appear in the list (its for a message system).

**This is the laravel php query I have:**

```
$users =  User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', $firstname.'%')->whereNotIn('id', $user_id)->get();
```

I want to check for users with matching first name but I want it to not grab a user with the id of `user_id`. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Note: `->whereNotIn("id", [$user_id])` would work, but doesn't make much sense for a single ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `->where('id', '!=', $user_id)` to get all users that do not share the id with `$user_id`.

In the code you have presented, that would result in the following:

```
User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', $firstname.'%')->where('id', '!=', $user_id)->get()
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many StackOverflow users are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted, so will not learn from your answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
$users =  User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', $firstname.'%')->where('id','<>', $user_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

this should work

```
$users =  User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', $firstname.'%')->where('id', '!=', $user_id)->get();
```

Comment: You guys are quick!

Comment: early morning , like rush hour  :)

Answer (score 0):

pass user_id as array, i.e. `[ $user_id ]`:

```
$users =  User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', $firstname.'%')->whereNotIn('id', [$user_id])->get()
```

Comment: Why did you choose for `whereNotIn` instead of a regular `where('id', '!=', $user_id)` or  `where('id', '<>', $user_id)`?

Comment: @Daan, that's how it was in the question, so this was the quickest fix. This will work, so it shouldn't be downvoted, not necessary with only one element but it does make it more easily expandable for additional ids in the future.

Comment: @Daan i think you got the ans. i know it's not a good way to used whereNotIn for  single id